# I want the push notification work for registered member

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, phonegap-build

i am trying to register the devuice fror push notification using the phonegap plugin. In the success action of the AJAX i call the registration action but its not alerting the registration ID. can anyone figure out it.

**here the index.js**

```
// Begin boilerplate code generated with Cordova project.
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function () {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    connectionStatus = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';

 if(connectionStatus !="online")
 {
     //$.mobile.changePage($("#seconddiv"));
     window.location.replace("no-internet.html");
 }
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function () {
},
setupPush: function() {
    console.log('calling push init');
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "xxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "ios": {
            "sound": true,
            "vibration": true,
            "badge": true
        },
        "windows": {}
    });
    console.log('after init');

    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        console.log('registration event: ' + data.registrationId);

        var oldRegId = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
        if (oldRegId !== data.registrationId) {
            // Save new registration ID
            localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId);
            // Post registrationId to your app server as the value has changed
        }
        alert(localStorage.getItem('registrationId'));

        var parentElement = document.getElementById('registration');
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.waiting');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    });

    push.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("push error = " + e.message);
    });

    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log('notification event');
        navigator.notification.alert(
            data.message,         // message
            null,                 // callback
            data.title,           // title
            'Ok'                  // buttonName
        );
   });
}
};
```

i call the **app.setupPush();** inside the ajax success handler

**here the signin.js**

```
var KPSCtuts = KPSCtuts || {};
$("#btn-submit").click(function(){
var userName = $("#txt-username").val();
var password = $("#txt-password").val();
//alert(KPSCtuts.Settings.Url);
$("#loaderIcon").show();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    url: KPSCtuts.Settings.Url,
    data:"username=" + userName + "&password=" + password + "&login=",
    success: function (resp) {

        if (resp.success === true) {
            // Create session. 
            var today = new Date();
            var expirationDate = new Date();
            expirationDate.setTime(today.getTime() + KPSCtuts.Settings.sessionTimeoutInMSec);
            KPSCtuts.Session.getInstance().set({
                userProfileModel: resp.userProfileModel,
                userId: resp.userId,
                userName: resp.userName,
                sessionId: resp.sessionId,
                expirationDate: expirationDate,
                keepSignedIn:$('#chck-rememberme').is(":checked")
            });
app.setupPush();
            // Go to main menu.
            window.location.replace("index.html");
            $("#loaderIcon").hide();
            return;
        } else {
            if (resp.extras.msg) {


                        $("#ctn-err").html("<p>"+resp.extras.msg+"</p>");
                        $("#dlg-invalid-credentials").show();
                        $("#ctn-err").addClass("bi-ctn-err").slideDown();
                        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

            }
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        //$.mobile.loading("hide");
        //console.log(e.message);
        // TODO: Use a friendlier error message below.
        $("#ctn-err").html("<p>1-Oops! KPSCtuts had a problem and could not log you on.  Please try again in a few minutes.</p>");
        $("#ctn-err").addClass("bi-ctn-err").slideDown();
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the registration code in onDeviceReady function.Registration ID will be same until you uninstall the app.

In HTML:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

In Script:

```
function onLoad()
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
   var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "xxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "ios": {
            "sound": true,
            "vibration": true,
            "badge": true
        },
        "windows": {}
    });

    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        console.log('registration event: ' + data.registrationId);

    });

    push.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("push error = " + e.message);
    });

    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log('notification event');
        navigator.notification.alert(
            data.message,         // message
            null,                 // callback
            data.title,           // title
            'Ok'                  // buttonName
        );
   });
}
```

Comment: i only want to send notification to registered members. how i can check it

Comment: send the registration id inside the login request along with other parameters and save it in the database along with the user info.So you could track only those user which are active in your database.